# striping a list into individual members in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm have a specific column in big query which is a list: details_ip_ranges.owner
instead of a list, I want to break it up into individual members as below, but I get an error:

What I have:

```
IP        details_ip_ranges.owner
1.2.3.4   Amazon
          Google
```

What I want:

```
IP        details_ip_ranges.owner
1.2.3.4   Amazon
1.2.3.4   Google
```

I read about the UNNEST function and tried it like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM `shared_ips` sp join `nodes` sn on sp.value = sn.value 
cross join UNNEST (sn.details_ip_ranges.owner) as owner
```

I get:

```
Cannot access field owner on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<as_number STRING, owner STRING>> at [3:36]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```
SELECT IP, range.owner as owner
FROM `shared_ips` sp join `nodes` sn on sp.value = sn.value 
cross join UNNEST (sn.details_ip_ranges) as range
```